# Moq not returning times result

Tags: c#, moq

Trying to use Moq for simple test. My test is as below

```
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        // Arrange
        string[] data = new string[] { "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat" };

        var mock = new Mock<DayList>();
        mock.Setup( x => x.AddDayNames( It.IsAny<string[]>() ) );
        mock.Setup( x => x.Add( It.IsAny<string>() ) );

        // Action
        DayList proc = new DayList(  );
        proc.AddDayNames( data );

        //mock.Object.AddDayNames( data );  --- This has the same result

        // Verify
        mock.Verify( m => m.Add( It.IsAny<string>() ), Times.Exactly( 7 ) );

    }
```

My class is as below

```
public class DayList
{
    private List<Days> ListOfDays = new List<Days>();

    public virtual void Add(string day)
    {
        ListOfDays.Add(new Days{ Name = day} );
    }

    public virtual void AddDayNames( string[] days)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < days.Length; i++ )
        {
            Add( days[i] );
        }
        
    }
    

}
```

My test fails and the reason "Expected invocation on the mock exactly 7 times, but was 0 times: m => m.Add(It.IsAny())" I don't understand why its 0 times. Please help

Comment: You create your mock but never use it? Normaly you get the object from the mock (myMock.Object) then you pass it to another function/object.
And in this case there is no need for mock. Mock are used to "simulate" a dependency but here everything is in the same class so you don't really need a mock.

Comment: Its the same result even if I do mock.Object.AddDayNames( data );

Comment: Yes but in that case the "AddProcedureNames" is the one from the mock so it does nothing :-) Actually you would like the method "AddDayNames" of the actual class calling the method "Add" of the mock. It's not possible.

Comment: Sorry that was a copy paste error

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. This question should include more details and clarify the problem.